# Proof that continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose $\Gamma$ is a curve $y = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $f$ is continuous. Show that $m(\Gamma)=0.$
>
> [Hint: Cover $\Gamma$ by rectangles, using the uniform continuity of $f$.]

My attempt:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Take the real line and consider the segments with endpoints at the integers. Without loss of generality now consider the segment $[0,1].$ Note that this is a closed and bounded set, so $f$ is uniformly continuous on it. Let $0<\delta<1$ be the one that works for this uniform continuity, and if necessary, pick a smaller $\delta$ which can partition the interval evenly. Then we can write $[0,1]=[0,\delta]\cup[\delta,2\delta]\cup\cdot\cdot\cdot\cup[n\delta,1],$ for some $n\geq1$.

Then for $x\in [i\delta,(i+1)\delta],$ with $i=0,\dots,n-1$, the curve is enclosed inside a rectangle of width $\delta$ and height $2\varepsilon$. Hence the measure of that portion of the curve is smaller than or equal to $2\delta\varepsilon.$ Since $\varepsilon>0$ was  arbitrary, it follows that each such portion of the curve has measure zero, and hence the same follows for every other portion.

Repeating this process for every other interval in the real line with endpoints at the integers yields the same result, and thus by countable sub-additivity, the result follows.

---

Is the proof above correct? Any comments are welcomed, be it about correctness or the quality of the style of the proof.

Thank you for your time and feedback.

Comment: Your proof seems fine by me. However I’m not too familiar with measure theory

Comment: Seems correct to me as well.

Comment: I don't see why the height of the rectangle is $2\varepsilon$, is that information contained in the $\delta$ ?

Comment: @P.Quinton You're right, the height should be $\varepsilon$ since for all $x,y \in [i\delta,(i+1)\delta]$ we have $f(x)-f(y)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: That's due to the uniform continuity and the factor $2$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I see why it's true but that's maybe something worth justifying, for example by replacing "the $\delta$ that works" part

Comment: I guess with continuous curve you mean the graph of a continuous function $f\colon \bb{R} \to \bb{R}$. Otherwise this is false due to the peano curve.